# Django query sum values from related table

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two tables:

Ticket Table

```
id  paid_with_tax
1   5
2   6
3   7
```

TicketAdjustment Table

```
id  ticket_id  value_with_tax
1   1          2
2   1          1
3   1          2
4   1          3
5   2          5
```

The query I use:

```
use = 0

Ticket.objects.all().annotate(
   paid_amount=Sum(
        F('paid_with_tax') +
        Coalesce(F('ticketadjustment__value_with_tax'), 0) * use
    )
)
```

the query would return the following:

```
[
    {id: 1, paid_amount: 7},
    {id: 1, paid_amount: 6},
    {id: 1, paid_amount: 7},
    {id: 1, paid_amount: 8},
    {id: 2, paid_amount: 11},
    {id: 3, paid_amount: 7},
]
```

but the above is incorrect since the Ticket Table id=1 values are duplicated by the TicketAdjustment Table values.

how can i get the query to sum the TicketAdjustment Table values and return the following:

```
[
    {id: 1, paid_amount: 13},
    {id: 2, paid_amount: 11},
    {id: 3, paid_amount: 7},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution for your problem :

```
Ticket.objects.all().annotate(
   paid_amount=(F('paid_with_tax') +
        Sum(Coalesce(F('ticketadjustment__value_with_tax'), 0))
    )
).values_list('id', 'paid_amount')
```

`values_list` select the field you want in your result.

In your primary request there is a big problem.

```
Sum(F('paid_with_tax') + Coalesce(F('ticketadjustment__value_with_tax'), 0) * use)
```

This ligne miltiply `value_with_tax` with zero. So give you zero. It's like :

```
Sum(F('paid_with_tax'))
```

You want the sum of `value_with_tax` for each ticket, this is why I move  `Sum` on it :

```
Sum(Coalesce(F('ticketadjustment__value_with_tax'), 0))
```

And after add the value of `paid_with_tax`

NB : I remove your variable `use`, because don't know is goal.